# python how to change ending of code

Tags: python, python-2.7, pydub

Im trying to figure out how to edit the ending of this string:

```
select_file = AudioSegment.from_(select_file)
```

what I'm trying to make it do is for the format of the file selected (In this case, a .wav file), to change the AudioSegment to extract for each file. I.e: If i select a ".mp3" file, AudioSegment.from_wav  will change to AudioSegment.from_mp3.

How can i accomplish this?  It seems that any attempt to make it flexible results in this error

```
AttributeError: type object 'AudioSegment' has no attribute 'from_SoundFile'
```

Here is the full code.

```
for file in os.listdir("Music"):
if file.endswith(".wav") or file.endswith(".mp3"):
    print file

select_file = raw_input("Which file would you like to modify?")
if select_file in os.listdir("Music"):
    os.chdir("Music")
    print select_file
    FileEnd = select_file.split(".")
    print FileEnd[-1]
    select_file = AudioSegment.from_SoundFile[-1](select_file)   

SoundFile = { 'Name': select_file, 'format': FileEnd[-1]}
```

How do i make it so that the ending will change depending on the file ending?  I don't need it to fit any specific type of code, so any answer is fine.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense to me. Why are you reassigning `select_file` at all? What is `from_SoundFile`?

Comment: There's clearly some misunderstandings in the approach you have taken so it would be beneficial from the point of view of what level to pitch an answer at by knowing what the actual problem you are trying to solve with this code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it is a good idea to use [`os.path.splitext`](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/audio_segment.py#L421) to get your file extension.

```
filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext('example_song.mp4')
```

After that you have a couple of options for selecting the correct pydub function. To understand the API I'd suggest having a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown), there you see that you can use `from_file` with the `format` keyword argument:

```
AudioSegment.from_file(filename, format=file_extension)
```

Or use functions based on the extension you extracted:

```
if file_extension == "mp3":
    AudioSegment.from_mp3(output_filename)
```

You can see by looking in the [pydub source](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/audio_segment.py#L421) that `from_mp3` and similar are just aliases for `from_file` with certain formats.

To then export that to a file you might want to use the AudioSegment [`export`](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown#audiosegmentexport) method.

Comment: When i try that, i get this error:   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'boom'.         Any reason that happens?

Comment: I'm fairly sure if you spent a bit of time debugging it you would see the problem. If you have an audio file then what is missing in the file name "boom" ?

Comment: I just figured it out.  I had to combine your solution of AudioSegment.from_file(filename, format=file_extension) with select_file.split(".") as your os.path.splitext included the period.  Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)